# Unhide number navigation pages on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to unhide or show all of the pages info from page 1 - 10 in one single page. Please see screen shot. I'm using Google Chrome dev tools but I dont know what I need to do.

What do I need to type where to get all 10 pages to show?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqaFs.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7fns.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can show all the results from the search on one page on this website. On some websites you can choose to show all the results on one page others you can't. It depends on how the website was made.

If anyone else wants to try, [this is the website](https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=doctors).